# How do i send http request in java?

Tags: java, android

I added this method to my MainActivity.java
But i'm getting error on the static: Inner classes cannot have static declatarions.

```
protected  static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                //Create connection
                URL url = new URL(targetURL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                        Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                //Send request
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                        connection.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.close();

                //Get Response
                java.io.InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if not Java 5+
                String line;
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
                return response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }
```

I can remove the static and then i'm getting no errors.
But where do i call this method from now ? From inside the onCreate ?
Tried but it's not exist when i type excute....in the onCreate it's not exist can't call it.

How do i use this method ? And what should i put as urlParameters ?

Comment: You need to post your entire code.  So far, you only have shown us a single method (which looks correct from a cursory glance).

Comment: Just a tip: Try using Retrofit. it's a very easy to use library for HTTP requests. It's way better than HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer class which holds the "excutePost" is an inner class therefore it cannot have static methods in it. What you can do is move the outer class to a separate file and make it non static - this will solve your problem.